# integrate bonita and wso2 Identity Server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, wso2, bonita

I've configured wso2 IS to retrieve user information from AD, but now I don't know how to integrate Bonita 6.3.6 (community edition) with wso2 IS. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify which kind of integration are you aiming? A use case example would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: I've configured wso2 IS to retrieve user data from AD and now I want to authenticate bonita user throw wso2 IS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bonita BPM official documentation you will be able to find [a page that cover all the authentication process](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/user-authentication-3).
Recommended approach is either to:

- Use the JAAS implementation of the authentication service and use (or create) an appropriate JAAS login module (if you have access to Bonita BPM Subscription edition)
- Create a new authentication service (you can check [interface](https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-engine/blob/7.0.1/services/bonita-authentication/bonita-authentication-api/src/main/java/org/bonitasoft/engine/authentication/AuthenticationService.java) and [default implementation](https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-engine/blob/7.0.1/services/bonita-authentication/bonita-authentication-api-impl/src/main/java/org/bonitasoft/engine/authentication/impl/AuthenticationServiceImpl.java))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you write please an implementation of the authentication service? After creating the service which are the next step to do?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not available to write the implementation. You might want to [get in touch](http://www.bonitasoft.com/be-part-it/contact-us) with Bonitasoft that can provide expertise for such development.